# CSS Toolkits similar to Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass, less, twitter-bootstrap

I really like the [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/#) css toolkit, but the issue is that it uses LESS and I am using a Rails 3.1 application which already comes with SASS. I managed to get Twitter Bootstrap to work with LESS, but it just sounds messy to have SASS and LESS both (your opinions are welcome).

1. I was wondering if there are css toolkits out there similar to Twitter Bootstrap? and possibly as good looking? Please let me know
2. I am also curious, is there anyone here who has used twitter bootstrap and has experienced any issues? Please elaborate

Answer (score 5):

There is a port of bootstrap to Sass : [Sass bootstrap on github](https://github.com/jlong/sass-twitter-bootstrap)

As for issues, I haven't found anything really annoying so far. The biggest pain is certainly the dire documentation.

Comment: I tried using that. Were you able to modify the colors (through changing variable values) using SASS Bootstrap? Its documentation refers to using `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-1.1.1.css">` which seems like a pre-compiled css with hardcoded color values. I do see its /lib/preboot.scss using SCSS vars instead of LESS, but how to install this gem and use it in the app?

Comment: should I just download it and stick it in to my vendor/assets/stylesheets directory to use it? no gem?

Answer (score 5):

[HTML KickStart](http://www.99lime.com/) is similar to Bootstrap, and even has some extras that Bootstrap doesn't. It uses CSS and jQuery.

Answer (score 5):

you should check out [zurb-foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/). I had similar constraints for my project and really have not looked back. It is already packaged as a gem.

Answer (score 1):

This frameworkd use Sass
Link install in Ruby on Rails
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/rails.html

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this question is still active and appears in Google search results so I thought I'd post this.

Another framework which seems to be getting more well known is [Gumby](http://gumbyframework.com/). Gumby uses SASS and has a ton of cool features.